How to get the state preparation circuit using StatePreparation function in Qiskit
I want to use the StatePreparation function in qiskit to prepare a state.
For example I want to prepare the statevector [0, 1, 0, 0]. Here is the code that I use:
from qiskit.circuit.library import StatePreparation

stateprep = StatePreparation([0, 1, 0, 0])
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(stateprep, [0, 1])

I want to see how the circuit is actually implemented using the basis gate sets. To do this, I can just use:
qc_t = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['cx','u3'])

but qc_t gets one CX and several U3s that are not necessary, because actually we only need one U3 (X) gate. If I try a slightly more complicated state, qc_t will include a large number of CXs.
From the documentation, qiskit uses isometries to prepare the state. Is there a better way to show the circuit instead of using transpile?

I'm not sure to understand your problem, what isn't to your convenience in transpile? You could use the decompose method, but at the end of the day, the way the circuit is decomposed using a given gate set will be computed using the transpile function (or some pass manager). You're asking for another method to show the circuit, what should this method have that transpile doesn't?

transpile is convenient to use. It's just the number of CNOTs is way larger than I expected. So i am wondering if there is another way to show the circuit in qiskit rather than directly transpile to the basis gate sets.

I think you are partially answering your own question.
As you mentioned, StatePreparation uses the isometries approach described in the paper you linked if you pass an arbitrary Statevector. Therefore, the resulting circuit will be whatever that algorithm produces, independent of it being optimal or not.
However, if you look through the StatePreparation code, it can be seen that if you initialize a simple separable state using a label as a parameter rather than a list representing an arbitrary Statevector, then you get the much simpler circuit you are looking for.
For example, this code generates the circuit you were expecting to see:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.circuit.library import StatePreparation

stateprep = StatePreparation('01')
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(stateprep, [0, 1])
qc_t = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['u', 'cx'])


Thanks. If I want to prepare a bell state, then it cannot be initialized as a string for the input, right?

Correct, you need to use a vector in that case.
